# JavaScript/jQuery: Why is my increment not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I have two buttons and there is a form in between. One button says "+" and the other "-". I am trying to make increment/decrement buttons, but it is not properly working. 
It seems like addition is causing a problem where increment is not happening, and instead, concatenation is happening. For example, when the form value is 0, and "+" button is pressed, it changes the 0 to 01.
My JavaScript code has

```
//assume the oldValue read 0 from the form
newValue = oldValue + 1
alert(newValue); //this returns 01 instead of 1
```

When the oldValue is 01 and increment again, it returns 011. Why is this not incrementing, but concatenating the 1 at the end?
Surprisingly, decrement is working perfectly with the same code except that I have a minus where there is a plus.

How can you increment a form value in peace? and can anyone explain why "+ 1" does not work?

Comment: `+` is also used for string concatenation. If you `alert(typeof oldValue)` it will show up as a string, not a number.

Comment: `oldValue` is String. Convert it to Number.

Comment: THANKS! It is a shame that I did not realize the data read from the form is string. Makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newValue = Number(oldValue) + 1
```

I think you forgot to convert string to int.

Comment: Thanks! and yes, as other 2 commented, I forgot to convert the string value. I totally forgot that the data read from the form was in string form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
newValue = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
```

This is happening because oldValue datatype is string and when you add a Int to a String then the output is also a string. So you have to convert it into a number before adding some int value into it.

Answer (score 1):

**CASE 1:**

```
var a=1;
var b=2;

alert(a+b);// RESULT WILL BE 3
```

**CASE 2:**

```
var a='1';
var b=2;

alert(a+b);// RESULT WILL BE 12
```

> If you are getting values from a Form or something , your value will
>   be treated as a string (like '1') . You can convert if to number/int
>   by Using the Keyword `Number` , Like below

```
alert(Number(a)+b);
```